# How to parse in the timezone into this php prettyprint library to print out the time according to set timezone?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am currently using https://github.com/danielstjules/php-pretty-datetime for printing my times. Currently it is spitting out UTC time because that is what is in MYSQL. I have a `PrettyPrint.php` as a component:

```
<?php

namespace Component;

use PrettyDateTime\PrettyDateTime,
    Phalcon\Mvc\User\Component,
    DateTime,
    Component\User;

class PrettyPrint extends Component
{

public static function prettyPrint($dateTime, $refDateTime = 'now')
{
    $user = new User();
    date_default_timezone_set($user->getSessionUserTimeZone());
    $getDateTimeObject = function($dateType) {
        if (is_numeric($dateType)) { //Linux timestamp
            $date = (new DateTime())->setTimestamp((int)$dateType);
        } else if (is_string($dateType)) {
            $date = new DateTime($dateType);
        }
        return $date;
    };
    $date = $getDateTimeObject($dateTime);
    $refDate = $getDateTimeObject($refDateTime);
    if (is_a($date, 'DateTime') && is_a($refDate, 'DateTime')) {
        return PrettyDateTime::parse($date, $refDate);
    }
}

public static function excerpt($string, $len = 10)
{
    return substr($string, 0, $len);
}
}
```

I can get the user's timezone name such as "America/New-York" with `$user->getSessionUserTimeZone()` But I am not sure how to parse it in `return PrettyDateTime::parse($date, $refDate);`

This is the `PrettyDateTime.php` from the src inside the github and the parse function is there but I am not sure what to do:

```
<?php

namespace PrettyDateTime;

class PrettyDateTime
{
// The constants correspond to units of time in seconds
const MINUTE = 60;
const HOUR   = 3600;
const DAY    = 86400;
const WEEK   = 604800;
const MONTH  = 2628000;
const YEAR   = 31536000;

/**
 * A helper used by parse() to create the human readable strings. Given a
 * positive difference, corresponding to a date in the past, it appends the
 * word 'ago'. And given a negative difference, corresponding to a date in
 * the future, it prepends the word 'In'. Also makes the unit of time plural
 * if necessary.
 *
 * @param  integer $difference The difference between dates in any unit
 * @param  string  $unit       The unit of time
 * @return string  The date in human readable format
 */
private static function prettyFormat($difference, $unit)
{
    // $prepend is added to the start of the string if the supplied
    // difference is greater than 0, and $append if less than
    $prepend = ($difference < 0) ? 'In ' : '';
    $append = ($difference > 0) ? ' ago' : '';

    $difference = floor(abs($difference));

    // If difference is plural, add an 's' to $unit
    if ($difference > 1) {
        $unit = $unit . 's';
    }

    return sprintf('%s%d %s%s', $prepend, $difference, $unit, $append);
}

/**
 * Returns a pretty, or human readable string corresponding to the supplied
 * $dateTime. If an optional secondary DateTime object is provided, it is
 * used as the reference - otherwise the current time and date is used.
 *
 * Examples: 'Moments ago', 'Yesterday', 'In 2 years'
 *
 * @param  DateTime $dateTime  The DateTime to parse
 * @param  DateTime $reference (Optional) Defaults to the DateTime('now')
 * @return string   The date in human readable format
 */
public static function parse(\DateTime $dateTime, \DateTime $reference = null)
{
    // If not provided, set $reference to the current DateTime
    if (!$reference) {
        $reference = new \DateTime(NULL, new \DateTimeZone($dateTime->getTimezone()->getName()));
    }

    // Get the difference between the current date and the supplied $dateTime
    $difference = $reference->format('U') - $dateTime->format('U');
    $absDiff = abs($difference);

    // Get the date corresponding to the $dateTime
    $date = $dateTime->format('Y/m/d');

    // Throw exception if the difference is NaN
    if (is_nan($difference)) {
        throw new Exception('The difference between the DateTimes is NaN.');
    }

    // Today
    if ($reference->format('Y/m/d') == $date) {
        if (0 <= $difference && $absDiff < self::MINUTE) {
            return 'Moments ago';
        } elseif ($difference < 0 && $absDiff < self::MINUTE) {
            return 'Seconds from now';
        } elseif ($absDiff < self::HOUR) {
            return self::prettyFormat($difference / self::MINUTE, 'minute');
        } else {
            return self::prettyFormat($difference / self::HOUR, 'hour');
        }
    }

    $yesterday = clone $reference;
    $yesterday->modify('- 1 day');

    $tomorrow = clone $reference;
    $tomorrow->modify('+ 1 day');

    if ($yesterday->format('Y/m/d') == $date) {
        return 'Yesterday';
    } else if ($tomorrow->format('Y/m/d') == $date) {
        return 'Tomorrow';
    } else if ($absDiff / self::DAY <= 7) {
        return self::prettyFormat($difference / self::DAY, 'day');
    } else if ($absDiff / self::WEEK <= 5) {
        return self::prettyFormat($difference / self::WEEK, 'week');
    } else if ($absDiff / self::MONTH < 12) {
        return self::prettyFormat($difference / self::MONTH, 'month');
    }

    // Over a year ago
    return self::prettyFormat($difference / self::YEAR, 'year');
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the DateTime object to this class, so why don't you run:

```
$date = new DateTime($inputDate, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('New/Timezone'));
```

Then pass $date to the prettyprint class.

---

Then I read more into the class and thought about it.  Does changing the timezone have any effect on a class like this?  It doesn't matter what the user's timezone is.  59 minutes ago is 59 minutes ago anywhere (on Earth anyways).

Comment: Oh, you are right. I didn't look into the class well enough and I saw support for timezone in the comments. Thanks alot!